# Kotlin with Java 9 Modules - Main class cannot be found in the module graph

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, cucumber

I'm adding a cucumber 'component test' to my Springboot project.
I'm using @SpringBootTest so the test shares the same JVM as the application (except the main class).

I have a separate source set for my cucumber test in build.gradle.kts -

```
val SourceSet.kotlin: SourceDirectorySet
    get() = project.extensions.getByType<KotlinJvmProjectExtension>().sourceSets.getByName(name).kotlin

sourceSets {
    create("cucumber") {
        kotlin.srcDirs( "src/cucumber")
        compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output + configurations["testRuntimeClasspath"]
        runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath + sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task<Test>("cucumber") {
    description = "Runs the cucumber tests"
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["cucumber"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["cucumber"].runtimeClasspath
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My project source sets now look like this -

[image]

I want the test to be black box.
So, I'd like to prevent my 'cucumber' source set from having access to any of the code in my 'main' source set.

I'm using Java 9 modules to try and achieve this, here is my 'cucumber' module-info.java -

```
open module at {
    requires com.johncooper.reactiveKotlin;
    requires ...
}
```

and here is my 'main' module-info.java -

```
module com.johncooper.reactiveKotlin {
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
  requires ...
  exports com.johncooper.reactiveKotlin;
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error when running my 'cucumber' test -

> > Task :compileCucumberKotlin FAILED e: Module com.johncooper.reactiveKotlin cannot be found in the module graph

I've tried putting the module-info.java files into a java root folder (suggested in another post) without success.

Does anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to avoid Java 9 modules and use Kotlin's own native module functionality!
Here is the the documentation from the Kotlin team - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#modules